# Finding a list of strings in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a personnel tracker, I'd like to "double check" that I have the people I need on a given day. With people as rows, and dates as the columns, I want to check the column for a particular day to see if I have coverage at a glance.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(BR4:BR46,{"Mc";"Ec";"M";"F";"Fe";"W";"Fe";"Ca";"Ce"}))>=7,"T","F")
```

This seems to work, but after some experimentation it is counting other strings in the column (so `W` or `F` might match on `WF`) which isn't what I want.

Comment: No repro. COUNTIFS doesn't match `W` or `F` on `WF` unless you use wildcard(s).

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIFS` works differently when you use an array as the criteria. It outputs an array the size of criteria showing have many matches were made for each item in criteria. Instead of using `SUMPRODUCT`, you need to count the number of values above 0. I've solved it by forcing every value of 0 in the array to be an error, and counting all non-errors.

```
=IF(COUNT(COUNTIFS(BR4:BR46,{"Mc";"Ec";"M";"F";"Fe";"W";"Fe";"Ca";"Ce"})^0)>=7,"T","F")
```